# I'm developing a wordpress theme and using custom fields. I've got the following code:

Tags: image, wordpress, templates, post, thumbnails

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true);?>" alt="Post Pic" width="615" height="275" /></a>
```

That code is giving this:

```
<img src="" alt="Post Pic" width="615" height="275">
```

Any ideas to why the image is not displaying correctly?

Comment: is this wordpress related?

Comment: The images won't display in post or thumbnails........I'm using the featured imaged

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to display the featured image for a post is with the [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) to echo the `<img>` tag to your page or [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) to return the result as a string. You should not be using custom/meta fields directly.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is because the meta field thumbnail isn't filled. If you're trying to display the thumbnail of the post, you can use the function [get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

You can also try the following code if you want to populate just the `src` of the `img` tag

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($item->ID)); ?>" alt="Post Pic" width="615" height="275" /></a>
```